# Why DynamoDB default import pipeline is not loading any data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have successfully exported a table with a single row from DynamoDB to S3. I then cleared the table and tried to import the same file back in but I can't get it to work.

Rephrasing what [import data from Amazon S3 to DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataPipelineExportImport.Importing.html) paragraph (5.a) says that I should put the file in `s3://bucket[/prefix]/tablename/YYYY-MM-DD_HH.MM`.

The export generates a different layout of the data, so I moved the file where the documentation says. I.e. `s3://mybucket/dynamodb/mytable/2014-05-29_14.32`, and I configured the pipeline to look in `s3://mybucket/dynamodb`.

I then setup an import job which ran without returning any error, yet the table was left empty.

The logs generated by the pipeline are not clear unfortunately.

Did anyone managed to import data in [DynamoDB format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-pipelinejson-verifydata2.html) from S3?

Answer (score -1):

While exporting DynamoDB table, backup data is put to s3 path with format : `output_s3_path/region/tableName/time`
where
tableName is dynamoDB table which is being backed up
region is region of the table
output_s3_path is "S3 Output Folder" field on console/UI

```
Example let 
tableName = test
region = us-east-1
output_s3_path = s3://test-bucket
```

Backup is generated in s3 path s3://test-bucket/us-east-1/test/2014-05-30_06.08

For importing this data, set value of "S3 Input Folder" same as generated path i.e. "s3://test-bucket/us-east-1/test/2014-05-30_06.08" .  "S3 Input Folder" should be the s3 prefix where data files exists.